# How to plot the probility of a data sequence

Tags: matlab, probability, matlab-figure

I have been working with a data set like

```
**Dist. Mode**
148528  3
76184   2
75828   2
53274   2
103112  3
74440   2
52880   3
51800   3
81788   3
82588   3
96216   3
85808   3
49978   3
75324   2
71258   2
36586   3
11740   2
15270   2
69870   1
52258   3
```

There are about 10k data. Left column shows the distortion and the right column show the modes (video mode) with respect to distortion.

I want to plot a probability curve where it will be possible to show the probability of mode(1, 2 ,3) at a particular point (distortion).

How can I solve it using MATLAB?

Comment: use `hist` and `accumarray`.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you some general pointers, but I'm not a Matlab expert, so I won't be able to give you code I'm afraid.

You want P(mode|dist). Since dist has a large range of values, I'd probably recommend modelling the opposite conditional distribution and transforming via Bayes theorem. To do so, assume a parametric form for (dist|mode)---Normal, let's say. Learn parameters via maximum likelihood (mean and std, set using samples of the particular mode). Then apply the following:

p(mode|dist) \propto p(dist|mode) * p(mode)

If you specifically want a probability just normalise these scores by their sum. p(dist|mode) is the Normal distributions you estimated, and p(mode) can just be the relative frequencies of the modes.